# select section name where marks of every student rounded to 10

Tags: mysql

table

```
Sec            marks
....................
a               10
a               20
a               30
b               5
b               10
b               25
c               40
c               53
c               37
```

desired output

```
...............
sec      marks
...............
a         10
a         20  
a         30
```

but i am getting all the sections a,b&c
i tried
.........

```
select sec,marks from students where marks%10=0;
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: i am using mysql database

Comment: what's wrong with getting `(b, 10)` and `(c, 40)`?

Comment: I need to display the section code if all the marks in that section are rounded to 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only the sect where all the value are "rounded to 10"
you could use a not in with a subselect  this way

```
select sec from my_table 
where sec not in (select sect 
                  from my_table 
                  where mod(marks, 10) != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN` to exclude those `sec` which have one or more row with marks not fully divisible by 10:

```
select *
from students
where sec not in (
        select sec
        from students
        where marks % 10 <> 0
        );
```